# Правила преобразования между float и size_t

Tags: c, float

Никак не могу найти информацию по правилам преобразования:

```
float  -> size_t
size_t -> float
```

Понятно, что при преобразовании числа с плавающей точкой в целое число происходит отбрасывание дробной части:

```
3.1f -> 3
3.9f -> 3
```

Я работаю над системой анимации. У меня есть диапазон кадров анимации, и есть счетчик текущего кадра:

```
size_t first_frame,
       last_frame;
float current_frame;
```

Я бы хотел проигрывать анимацию примерно так:

```
current_frame += dt;
if (current_frame > last_frame)
{
    current_frame = first_frame;
}
```

То есть, зацикливать кадры из определенного диапазона.

Но поскольку при записи во `float` целых чисел происходит потеря точности, я бы хотел более подробно понять этот процесс.

Я переживаю из-за такой ситуации:

```
// В s1 есть какое-то число, не обязательно 7.
size_t s1 = 7;

// 7 -> 6.99997 или 7.00003?
float f = s1;

// Если f = 6.99997, то s1 != s2.
size_t s2 = f;
```

То есть, происходит ли искажение с запасом в большую сторону, или же искажение осуществляется в меньшую сторону?

Comment: О каком искажении речь? 7 переводится в 7.0000. Никаких 6,9999 или 7,00003 там нет. _Но поскольку при записи во float целых чисел происходит потеря точности_ - почему вы так думаете?

Comment: Я говорю не обязательно про семерку.

Comment: Да неважно. Целые числа переводятся во float без всяких потерь и искажений. С чего вы взяли, что там какие-то искажения?

Comment: А почему вообще текущий кадр - дробная величина? Если это результат деления времени на частоту кадров, то его нужно округлять вниз до целого.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, я это понимаю. Я хочу разобраться, какое значение используется при конвертации `size_t` во `float` - ближайшее меньшее или ближайшее большее?

Comment: Используйте функцию округления типа [`lround`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/lround/).

Comment: @Эникейщик "_Целые числа переводятся во float без всяких потерь и искажений_"... Да ладно ... https://ideone.com/ExpsVH

Comment: @Mike Блин, я подозревал, что когда-то разрядов не хватит, но не думал, что на таком маленьком числе...

Comment: При конвертации int во float стандарт IEEE 754 требует, чтобы результат был гарантированно целым. Причем в пределах точности (-999999...999999 для одинарной точности) результат будет строго равен исходному int.

Comment: @Эникейщик Кстати, провел тест, минимальное число дающее сбой 16777217. Это на 2 больше предела хранения 3х байт. И в float под мантису как раз отведено 3 байта, так что все предсказуемо.

Comment: В общем, как я понял, без правильных округлений никак не обойтись. `size_t s = f + 0.5f;` считается правильным математическим округлением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `size_t` -> `float`

  Спецификация стандартного преобразования целочисленного значения к плавающему типу говорит, что если исходное целочисленное значение представимо в целевом плавающем типе *точно*, то результатом преобразования будет именно оно. Если исходное целочисленное значение НЕ представимо в целевом плавающем типе точно, то результатом преобразования будет либо *ближайшее большее* представимое целое, либо *ближайшее меньшее* представимое целое. Способ выбора определяется реализацией.

  Поэтому потеря точности при записи целых во `float` действительно возможна, но нецелый результат при этом получиться никак не может.
- `float`  -> `size_t`

  В преобразовании плавающего значения к целочисленному типу происходит отбрасывание дробной части. Если результат не помещается в диапазон целочисленного типа, то поведение не определено.

Comment: Каким же образом можно побороть описанную мной проблему? Я бы хотел хранить индексы первого и последнего кадра в виде целых чисел, а позицию текущего кадра - в виде числа с плавающей точкой.